# Java: having files containing only general methods?

Tags: java

I was wondering if there was a way to have methods separated from the main and class files (like how in c you can have .c & .h with just methods that you can import into projects).

Specifically I have a 'logical exclusive or' function that I want to use across several classes and I thought it would be good practice not to have the same function repeated across several classes.

Answer (score 2):

They're called function libraries and yes you can do them. The best example is `java.lang.Math`.

You make a final class with a private constructor, no variables, and all static methods.

```
public final class FuncLib {

    private FuncLib() { } // prevents instantiation

    public static String formatAwesomely(String foo) {
        // code
    }

    public static int calculateScore(BaseballGameData data) {
        // code
    }

}
```

Comment: I think the general term for the pattern is "utility class".

Comment: Hmm, never called them that in my organization, but i think that's perfectly appropriate! :-)

Comment: Just "a class with all static methods" will work, the rest serves to prevent the class being accidentally used in an unintended way.

Comment: @Sii that is true, the rest are simply safeguards. They're safeguards I'd highly recommend enough to say they're required. While it's not entirely true, it's true enough that I'd be willing to lie about it. :-)

Comment: For "good design" you should give the class a private no-args constructor, which prevents (pointless) instantiation.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, you have to shove everything into a class. The general convention is having a class named `Utils` (or `BooleanUtils` or whatever organisation / naming convention you like) and putting generic pure functions into it as static methods.

Java 5 and later have a [static import](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html) feature to make using this sort of functions less verbose.

Answer (score -1):

With Java being an object-oriented language you might want to think about what your goal is.  Traditionally with object-oriented design, if multiple objects really do have a single common ancestor method which is common across them, in all likely hood all of those classes should be sub-classes of that class.

Example:

Think about animals, lets say we have a dog and a cat.  All animals make noises.  You might have a method for "makeNoise()" which both classes need. A common setup would then to have one class of "Animal" and two sub-classes which extend the "Animal" class named "Dog" and "Cat".

In this case if the "makeNoise()" method as it stands for all animals is adequate for your more specific classes, then that is fine for them to use.  Additionally, perhaps a cat and a dog make a noise in the same way (from their mouth) but in the end it is a different noise (bark vs meow) and you can choose to override your "makeNoise()" method with any class specific attributes.

Comment: No inheritance example is complete without dogs and cats!

Comment: -1: I'm not sure how the vague OO proselytising is relevant to a question that deals with a textbook use case for global functions.